# how to get the value from 2 text area that have the same name, and save it in the slice

Tags: go

So I have a form in which there are 2 text areas, but these two text areas must have the same name, how do I get 2 values ​​from that text area and save them in a slice?

```
<form method="POST" action="/process">
    <textarea name="question"></textarea>
    <br/>
    <textarea name="question"></textarea>
    <input type="submit" value="Create!"/>
</form>
```

my golang code:

```
func processQuestion(w http.ResponseWritter, r *http.Request){
    if r.Method == "POST" {
        err := r.ParseForm()
        IsError(err)

        questions := []string{}

        for {
            question := r.FormValue("question")
            if question == nil {
                break
            }
            questions = append(questions, question)
        }
    }
    http.Error(w, " ", http.StatusBadRequest)
}
```

Comment: Which framework you are using?

Comment: @meshkati I only use net/http

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`r.FormValue("question")` returns the first value only, even if there are many. Use `r.Form["question"]` to get a list of all the values with the name `"question"`.

Comment: Glad to hear! Good luck with the rest of the project :)